# GmailApp.sendEmail stopped working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I had script that was working up until about a month ago.. No errors just plain stopped.

I've since tried to rewrite the script with some help from others but still nothing...

The Script is attached to a Google Form Response Spreadsheet. When the form is submitted it is supposed to send 2 emails out. One to the submitter and one to the recipient.

here's where I am at. Still no errors.. At least none that I know of.

```
function getResponseURL(timestamp) {
var id = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getFormUrl().match(/[\_\-\w]{25,}/);
var form = FormApp.openById(id);
var resp = form.getResponses(new Date(timestamp.getTime() - 1000*5));

if (resp.length) return resp[0].getEditResponseUrl(); else return "";
}

function SendGoogleForm(e) {
var val = {
/*
Enter column header for recipient address
For an example
'subject': 'Email'
*/
'recipient': 'Email',

/*
Enter your email alias
*/
'alias': 'email@themarcjosephband.ca',

/*
Receiver's email for the notifications:
*/
'to': 'info@themarcjosephband.ca',

/*
ReplyTo email for the receiver's notifications:
*/
'replyto' : 'info@themarcjosephband.ca',

/*
1. the subject includes a row number and the person's name automatically - just want to fill in the text afterwards
Change the 'subject' value below.
For an example
'subject': 'test'
OR
'subject': 'the text afterwards'
*/

'subject': 'Quote Request',
'subject2': 'Quote Request',

/*
2. the body of course includes the form fields that were filled in,  I just want to add text prior to that.
Change the 'text' value below.
For an example
'text': 'test'
OR
'text': 'add text prior to that'
*/

'text': 'The following quote request has been submitted.'
}

var recipient = "";

var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];    

var subject = "[#" + s.getLastRow() + "] " + e.namedValues["Name"].toString() + " " + val.subject;

var body, message = [['','']];

for(var i in headers) {
var col = headers[i];
if ( e.namedValues[col] && (e.namedValues[col].toString() !== "") && (col !== "Timestamp") && col !== "What is the color of oranges?" ) {
  message.push([col, e.namedValues[col].toString()]); 
  if (col === val.recipient) {
    recipient = e.namedValues[col].toString();
  }
}
}

var textBody = "", htmlBody = "";  
for (var i=0; i<message.length; i++) {
htmlBody += "<tr><td><strong>" + message[i][0] + '</strong></td><td>'+ message[i][1] + "</td></tr>";
textBody += message[i][0] + " :: " + message[i][1] + "\n\n";
}
htmlBody = val.text + "<br /><br /><table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2'>" + htmlBody + "</table>";
textBody = val.text + "\n\n" + textBody;

var responseURL = getResponseURL(new Date(e.namedValues["Timestamp"].toString()));

/*
3. the body also includes a line with a link to edit the response at the end.
It's below
*/

if (responseURL !== "") {

htmlBody = htmlBody + "<br><br>" + "You can edit the response by <a href='" + responseURL + "'>clicking here</a>.";

textBody = textBody + "\n\n" + "Click the link below to edit the response:\n" + responseURL;

}

GmailApp.sendEmail ( val.to, subject, textBody, {
htmlBody: htmlBody, replyTo: recipient, from: val.alias } );

GmailApp.sendEmail ( recipient, val.subject2, textBody, {
htmlBody: htmlBody, replyTo: val.replyto, from: val.alias } );        

}

function Authorize() {
 Browser.msgBox("Script authorized.");
}


function InitializeTriggers() {

Reset(true);

 ScriptApp.newTrigger("SendGoogleForm")
 .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
 .onFormSubmit()
 .create();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your `SendGoogleForm()` function is being run as an `onFormSubmit` trigger, any errors in the code will be reported to you through an automated e-mail from Google Apps Script.  Have you checked the script owner's inbox for a "Summary of failures for Google Apps Script" message from `apps-scripts-notifications@google.com`?

You could also try using `MailApp.sendEmail()` instead of `GmailApp.sendEmail()`.  Perhaps it will work more reliably?

Comment: When the script suddenly stopped there were no notifications sent. Which was what I meant by saying no errors. After testing these re-writes these are the errors sent to me last night  

Summary:
Error Message Count
Invalid argument: email@themarcjosephband.ca (line 133, file "Code") 
ReferenceError: "getResponseURL" is not defined. (line 113, file "Code")
Details:

SendGoogleForm Invalid argument: email@themarcjosephband.ca (line 133, file "Code") formSubmit

SendGoogleForm ReferenceError: "getResponseURL" is not defined. (line 113, file "Code") formSubmit